# Make Emacs highlight Java keywords

Tags: java, emacs

How do I make Emacs recognize Java keywords?

I want to use Emacs as a text editor that highlights the keywords of my code, because I want to run the code in terminal.

I tried to save my file as a Java file but it does not highlight it.

Comment: Do you edit the files in the `java-mode`?

Comment: No, how can i made it in java-mode?

Comment: My emacs turns to `java-mode` automatically when I open a java file. Try pressing `[M-x] java-mode [Enter]` to turn it on.

Comment: @chobra ..it works, that was help full